# secretOrPrivateKey must have a value Nodejs MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, .env

New to Nodejs, I'm currently on an authentication project. I manage to register a user but when I want to connect. there is an error.

**here is the error:**

```
E:\IMPORTANT\INFO-DEV\DEV\ANGULAR NODEJS\SYSTEM MANAGEMENT\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:107
    return failure(new Error('secretOrPrivateKey must have a value'));
                   ^

Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
    at module.exports [as sign] (E:\IMPORTANT\INFO-DEV\DEV\ANGULAR NODEJS\SYSTEM MANAGEMENT\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:107:20)
    at exports.createToken (E:\IMPORTANT\INFO-DEV\DEV\ANGULAR NODEJS\SYSTEM MANAGEMENT\backend\utils\jwt.js:8:37)      
    at exports.login (E:\IMPORTANT\INFO-DEV\DEV\ANGULAR NODEJS\SYSTEM MANAGEMENT\backend\controllers\auth.controller.js:34:25)

Node.js v18.12.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**My code config jwt:**

```
module.exports = { 
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    ttl: 3600
}
```

**My code jsonwebtoken:**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const jwtConfig = require("../config/jwt");

exports.verifyToken = (token) => jwt.verify(token, jwtConfig.secret);

exports.createToken = (data) =>
  jwt.sign(data, jwtConfig.secret, { expiresIn: jwtConfig.ttl });
```

**My file .env :**

```
PORT=3000
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
DB_NAME=inflouis
JWT_SECRET=inflouis
ttl=3600
```

The file auth `auth.controller.js`

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const jwt = require("../utils/jwt");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email,
  });
  if (user) {
    const isMatched = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (isMatched) {
      const token = jwt.createToken({ _id: user._id });
      return res.json({
        access_token: token,
        token_type: "Bearer",
        expires_in: jwtConfig.ttl,
      });
    }
  }
  return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid credentails." });
};
```

Comment: And where do you think you're _loading_ the env vars from the file?

Comment: Yes yes, normally. Because I manage to insert the user's data into the database during registration. Knowing that the name of the database comes from the .env file

Answer (score 1):

it seems like there is a problem in reading the .env file.

install the `npm i dotenv` package
and add the

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
```

or

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

try this! hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That wasn't the problem because I had done that before.
I printed the jwt secret value in console.log and it worked.
So I went straight to .env for the jwt configuration

```const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

exports.verifyToken = (token) => jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

exports.createToken = (data) =>
  jwt.sign(data, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: process.env.ttl });```

And it works.

Comment: Answer of @sumanth works for me. Thank you.